# Ignore results from mutation query using apollo client?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I want to use graphql to trigger an `addLicenseCodeOneTimeUsage` action on a server. I don't know what the server will respond with and I don't need any response. As you can see I list no properties in `addLicenseCodeOneTimeUsage{}`.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

yield client.mutate({
    /* tslint:disable */
    mutation: gql`
        }
        mutation licensemutation($distributor: String!, $licenceType: String!, $duration: String!, $userId: String!) {
            addLicenseCodeOneTimeUsage(distributor: $distributor, licenseType: $licenseType, duration: $duration, userId: $userId) {
            }
        }
    `,
    /* tslint:enable */
    variables: {
        userId: username,
        distributor: distributor,
        licenseType: licenseType,
        duration: duration,
    },
});
```

- Does what I have written this far sound reasonable or do I have obvious misconceptions about how graphql works or how it should be used?
- In the graphql string I don't define what information to receive. Is that syntax valid or do I need to explicitly state that I want to ignore results?

Answer (score 1):

The mutation’s return type must define at least one field and you must select at least one field from it in the query.  (See [§2.3 of the spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations).)

If you control both the server and the client and the mutation really returns nothing, you could define an artificial `ok: Boolean!` that’s always true.  You might return something like a user object that contains a list of entitlements too, in which case you could just select (and ignore) the user ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what [`ignoreResults`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#params-2) is for.

> `ignoreResults` - If true, the returned data property will not update with the mutation result.

So the mutation (with this option) would look like:

```
client.mutate({
    mutation: MutationDocument
    variables: {
        userId: username,
        distributor: distributor,
        licenseType: licenseType,
        duration: duration,
    },
    ignoreResults: true
});
```